# How can I register Google play developer console in the second time?

Tags: google-play

I want to register Google Developer Console, but I used to register for my friend and I use my name. Now, I want to register one more time, but I can't register it. Google teams wants me to provide the "Account Verification". Adding that, I have a few document to confirm, so I still not able to register. Do any have idea or suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just trying to create a new account?

Comment: I used to create new account, but it need Account Verification.

Comment: I don't understand what you're missing.  When I created my Play account, I created a whole new Google account for it - as it didn't want it tied to all my personal stuff.  I didn't have any trouble verifying anything.  What, specifically, are you missing?

Comment: The Google teams send the email and take me to the "screen shot above".

Comment: Oh.  I see.  You're trying to use the same card on a new account, and they want you to prove that it's REALLY your card, and you're not ripping someone off.  So why don't you just provide what they're asking for?

Comment: Could you me about the second point? I am not sure about it. what's the documents?

Comment: They are asking you for your ID and proof of billing address.  Those documents.

Comment: "proof of billing address" refer to my address in my visa card. Is that right?

Comment: Yes.  You normally have to provide a utility bill or something to prove it's really your address.

Comment: Thanks. I will try call to bank ask for utility bill and confirm to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, since it seems my comments served as an accepted answer...

Google won't accept payment on a new account if you are using a credit card that was previously used to open an account, unless you can prove that you are the actual owner of the card.  As such they will require documentation to prove that you are not stealing someone else's card to make a purchase.  In the case of the attached document, they are requesting and gov't issued ID, and a doc with proof of address matching that of the card (or Google Wallet) address.  Normally a utility bill would suffice for this.